# Clicking markers on Google Static Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have an application that downloads static images off Google maps, with markers placed where I want them (Placed by passing arguments into the Google Static Maps URL). However, I also need to be able to click the markers. I figured I could convert the x and y coordinate is the click to lon/lat, and then figure out that way which marker was clicked, but I haven't found that too easy.

I know the dimensions of the map in pixels, the zoom level, and the centre point of the map in pixels and lon/lat, so I followed [this blog post](http://www.appelsiini.net/2008/6/clickable-markers-with-google-static-maps). Unfortunately this didn't work.

Does anyone know how I could do this, or know another way I could figure out if a marker has been clicked? I'm forced to use the Static maps unfortunately, so I can't do any of it with the JavaScript API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:

http://home.provide.net/~bratliff/largetiles/

or

http://home.provide.net/~bratliff/harbor/

It is not exactly what you are doing but it does demonstrate Mercator projection conversions & cross-browser mouse events.